# Sending files through AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been using simple AWS Lamda functions and their SES service to create website contact forms.
I make a simple form in HTML then convert the information entered in to a JSON string object and email it to the site owner. 
Now I want to add the capability to upload different files that I intend to use a similar method to attach the files and email it using AWS Lambda and SES.
Here is my current status and code.

Here is the code I use to make a JSON Object that I later email through AWS Lambda

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $("#submit2").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var Firstname = $("#Firstname").val(),
                        Lastname = $("#Lastname").val(),
                        email = $("#email").val(),
                        phone = $("#Phone").val(),
                        address = $("#Address").val(),
                        backSplash = $("#BackSplash").val(),
                        material = $("#Material").val(),
                        message = $("#subject").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            'name': Firstname + " " + Lastname,
                            'phone':phone,
                            'address': address,
                            'email': email,
                            'backSplash' : backSplash,
                            'material': material,
                            'message': message
                        }),
                        success: function(res){
                            $('#form-response').text('Your Message Has been sent.');
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            $('#form-response').text('Error, Message was not sent, please try again.');
                        }
                    });

                })

            });`
```

In Terms of uploading files, here is my current code

```
            function getFiles(){

                    var files = document.getElementById("myFiles").files;
                    var myArray = [];
                    var file = {};

                    console.log(files); // see the FileList

                    // manually create a new file obj for each File in the FileList
                    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                      //console.log(files[i].name);
                      file = {
                          'lastMod'    : files[i].lastModified,
                          'lastModDate': files[i].lastModifiedDate,
                          'name'       : files[i].name,
                          'size'       : files[i].size,
                          'type'             : files[i].type,
                      } 
                      //add the file obj to your array
                      myArray.push(file)
                    }
                        //save the array to localStorage
                      localStorage.setItem('files',JSON.stringify(myArray));
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
                  }
                    });
```

How can I add the uploaded File to the data object I pass to my AWS Lamda function? and how can I allow the website owner to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to upload the file to S3 bucket, and then generate a pre-signed url that you email to the person who is supposed to receive it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: Alternatively, depending on file size, you could base64 encode it, pass it in the context, and attach it as part of the email directly. This would only work for very small files, though, of course, and your method allows for better tracking of who actually is clicking that download link.